# changed a defined value inside the element

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to change the defines css inside the div element of embed videos
example
this is the embed codes for poster

```
<div class="vjs-poster" tabindex="-1" 
style="background-image: url(streaming-auto-generated-poster.jpg);"></div>
```

I tried this code but it won't change the background since the default background are defined inside the div

```
.vjs-poster{
background-image:url(the post thumbnail);
}
```

what I want is to customized the background-image with my own

Answer (score 0):

CSS will use the most specific rule when multiple are applicable, and by default `style` will trump a class definition.  You can use `!important` to override this.

```
.vjs-poster {
  background-image: url(my-own-poster) !important;
}
```

More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).